# Flutter Go_router, save history of routes

Tags: flutter, gorouter

I have this code of router

```
final _router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const LoginScreenWidget();
      },
      routes: <RouteBase>[
        GoRoute(
          path: 'main',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return const MainScreenWidget();
          },
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: 'my-friends',
              builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                return const FriendsScreenWidget();
              },
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: ':userId',
                  builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                    return FriendProfileScreenWidget(
                      userId: state.params['userId'],
                    );
                  },
                  routes: [
                    GoRoute(
                      path: 'friends',
                      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                        return ProfileFriendsScreenWidget();
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

class AppRouterDelegate extends GetDelegate {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      onPopPage: (route, result) => route.didPop(result),
      pages: currentConfiguration != null
          ? [currentConfiguration!.currentPage!]
          : [GetNavConfig.fromRoute('main')!.currentPage!],
    );
  }
}
```

And on different screens I go deeper and deeper. And it works the way I need it. But when I click back, I don't move back through the history, but go back to the beginning

```
context.go('/main')
```

```
context.go('/main/my-friends')
```

```
context.go('/main/my-friends/${friendsList[index].id}')
```

```
context.go('/main/my-friends/${userId}/friends')
```

```
context.go('/main/my-friends/${friendsList[index].id}')
```

How do I make it so that when we click back, we return to the previous page, and not to the initial one?

back buttons have this code

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

At first I tried to do it through a regular Navigator, then through Navigator 2.0. But it didn't work. Then I found this go router and I liked it, but I can't solve the last problem

Comment: I found a solution with Navigator 2.0, but I am struggling with GoRouter... Did you find a solution? Here is the solution for Navigator 2.0
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66958888/7927429

Answer (score 3):

Use `context.push('routeName')` instead of `context.go('routeName')`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the go_router pop extension instead of Navigator.pop(context)?

```
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

context.pop();
```

Link to a page explaining the difference between push and go :
[Go vs Push](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-navigation-gorouter-go-vs-push/)